# How to remove Conflict in a jQuery plugin in a WordPress website?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, conflict, jquery

I am working on a WordPress website. I have few filters of jQuery in it and all are working fine (I initiate these plugins using):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  /*code here*/
});
```

I am also using a jQuery Plugin ["filter.js"](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js) which is having conflicting issues. Even when I do not initiate this plugin (only on linking the plugin file to my page) it shows jQuery conflict and I can see in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

You can find plugin source [here](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js/blob/master/filter.js).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping your code like this:

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){
         //document ready code here
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Wrap your filter.js plugin with the same wrapper, ie:

```
(function($){

    //filter.js code here

})(jQuery);
```

If that's not working - make sure jQuery is included on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using two different versions of JQuery in the same page?

If so then use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

just after the declaring the jQuery and replace all subsequet $ with jQuery

Hope it helps